# Loop Commands or Functions Until a Condition becomes True in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to show a Nice Welcome Animated GIF to my users when running my Program Installer created using Inno Setup.

I want to display some PNG Images to an order (As Inno Setup doesn't support displaying Animated GIFs yet) using `Isgsg.dll` until Setup finishes initializing my tons of codes.

I wrote a code to show those PNG Images in order, but it stops after last one is shown.

I need to continue showing from first PNG Image after last one shown before.

If Setup was initialized,(I mean if `WizardForm` is visible) the Looping Procedure should stop.

The Codes I wrote to display those PNG Images:

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  DlgWait: TForm;
if Result = True then begin
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome1.png');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome2.png');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome3.png');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome4.png');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome5.png');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome6.png');
ExtractTemporaryFile('Welcome7.png');
```

<<< LOOPING SHOULD BEGIN FROM HERE >>>

```
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome1.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome2.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome3.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome4.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome5.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome6.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome7.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
```

<<< LOOPING SHOULD CONTINUE FROM HERE IF NOT `WizardForm` VISIBLE, OTHERWISE LOOPING SHOULD BE STOPPED >>>

```
...
end;
```

How can I do this as I expect?

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I can't think why this Code is not working.

This DLL requires PNG File's Filename as an `AnsiString`.

But I've provided a `String`.

Is this gone wrong or any other Synatx Error Here for this to not working?

`Not Working` means those PNG Images Showing Loop Procedure not working.

The Code I tried to add to do this Conditional Loop using `Repeat Until`:

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  DlgWait: TForm;
  IMessageHandler: TForm;
  X: Integer;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  LblWait: TLabel;
if Result := True then begin
DlgWait := TForm.Create(nil);
DlgWait.Hide;
begin
Order:=1;
Repeat
ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome+IntToStr(Order)+.png'),0250,1000,0250,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
Order:=Order+1;
Until FileExists(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome+IntToStr(Order)+.png')) = False;
end;
end;
```

Are there any syntax Errors?

But Compiler doesn't give any Compiler Warning or Error.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please learn to correctly format your code, both here and in your code/text editor. It makes it much easier to read and maintain. The compiler doesn't care about whitespace, so properly indenting and placing spaces after commas and before and after + signs doesn't cost you anything but a keystroke, and it saves headaches and eyesight in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset your counter when you've reached the end. Something like this should get you started. (NOTE: Untested - I don't have InnoSetup on this machine. Replace the test in the `until` with whatever is appropriate to detect the WizardForm being visible.)

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  DlgWait: TForm;
  IMessageHandler: TForm;
  X: Integer;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  LblWait: TLabel;
const
  NumImages = 7;
begin
  if Result then 
  begin
    DlgWait := TForm.Create(nil);
    DlgWait.Hide;
    Order := 1;
    repeat
      ShowSplashScreen(DlgWait.Handle, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Welcome' + IntToStr(Order) + '.png'), 0250, 1000, 0250, 0,255, True, $FFFFFF, 10);
      Order := Order + 1;
      if Order > NumImages then
        Order := 1;
    until WizardForm.Visible;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank You , I will try this when I'm gone home and notify you what happened.

Comment: Great Work, Ken White..........Well done, it's working and looping works fine. But I can't give a condition whether to stop it.........Setup is stuck at this Looping Procedure because I set to `Until Order > 7` because when I try to set  `Until WizardForm.Visible`, `An attempt was made to access WizardForm before it has been created.` Error occurs. Any experienced Coder can give me a good Condition to stop looping when `WizardForm` Creates..... :-/

Comment: Order will never be `> 7`, because when it reaches 7 it gets reset to 1, and that would happen before the `until` part executes.. (Did you read the code I wrote, particularly the line `if Order > NumImages then Order := 1;`?) I don't know how to tell you when WizardForm becomes available, because I didn't write your code.

Comment: Yes, I read I forgotten to add `NumImages`...I will add now.I like to know why I can't set a condition like `if WizardForm.Visible`?

Comment: When I set the condition to `Until (Order = 7) and not WizardForm.Visible` Setup even stuck at looping...........Why this happens............Doesn't a condition happens like this?

Comment: I've explained why that Until will not break the loop - the **counter gets reset within the loop before the `until` executes**. That's how it keeps looping. Again, are you **reading the code I wrote**? And I can't help you with the check of WizardForm, because I don't have your code to see when it becomes visible or is created or whatever, so I can't tell you what to use to break the loop.

Comment: Okay..........Until not executes...........That's what I understood. If Until can't break the loop, I may need to set another condition for Counter - Resetting. If this also seems like impossible, can I tell pascal script to keep looping and move to the next code / script at least?? Like the Flag `ewNoWait` means? Can't I give the pascal script `ewNoWait` condition without using this flag as flags can't be used in these Procedures.

Comment: Until will break the loop, as soon as you find a condition that can be tested correctly.

Comment: No, I will also try adding it, but I also read a post which describes a failed try of a user when used it.

Comment: No, @JanWindemuth, the same su***** Error Occurred.

Comment: However I killed the loop by using `IsProcessRunning` function to `Until` which was added by me to detect if any process is running by its process name..................Here I given my Batch File's process name which takes long time to initialize.After the Batch File finishes initializing, the Loop Stops and Setup starts.......;)